# After deleting data page not redirect my index page

Tags: php

**Delete Button Code**

As you can see I'm trying to redirect the user index.php after deleting data. How can I do that?

Here is the action form:

```
<form action="scripts.php" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" name="delete_id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="del_new_name" value="<?php echo $row['new_name']; ?>">
      <button type="submit" name="delete_new_name" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
</form>
```

**Post Method Code**

Here is the post method code on scripts.php file:

```
//scripts.php File:
        
        if (isset($_POST['delete_new_name'])) {
            $id = $_POST['delete_id'];
            $new_name = $_POST['del_new_name'];
        
        
            $query = "DELETE FROM uploaded_files WHERE id='$id' ";
            $query_run = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        
            if ($query_run) {
                unlink("uploads/" . $new_name);
                $_SESSION['status'] = "Data Deleted Successfully";
                header('location: index');
                
                
            } else {
                $_SESSION['status'] = "Data Not Deleted";
                header('location: index.php');
                
            }
        }
```

**Session Status**

Here is the Session Status code on the index.php

```
<?php
      if (isset($_SESSION['status']) && $_SESSION != '') {
            ?>
              <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                <strong> Hey! </strong> <?php echo $_SESSION['status']; ?>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>

            <?php
              unset($_SESSION['status']);
            }
            ?>
```

It goes scripts.php file and deletes the data from the folder and database, after deleting it, it doesn't redirect index.php. I think I'm missing something plz help me out

Comment: Should `header('location: index');` actually say `header('location: index.php');` just like the other example in the same script? You said you wanted to redirect to "index.php", and "index" isn't the same as "index.php".

Comment: Be warned that your `DELETE` query is widely open for SQL injection. Also, what have you tried to resolve your problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Thanks for your edit, but...did you try my suggestion? It seems like the most likely cause of the issue.

Comment: On the redirect page. After deleting the data it holds on the scripts.php it doesn't redirect the index.php file

Comment: Letting you know

Comment: @ShakijMahamud so did that help? If not, then what error are you seeing when it fails to redirect? Have you switched on PHP error reporting?

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Answer (score -1):

Do not use the white space. Please check the below code.

//scripts.php File:

```
    if (isset($_POST['delete_new_name'])) {
        $id = $_POST['delete_id'];
        $new_name = $_POST['del_new_name'];
    
    
        $query = "DELETE FROM uploaded_files WHERE id='$id' ";
        $query_run = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    
        if ($query_run) {
            unlink("uploads/" . $new_name);
            $_SESSION['status'] = "Data Deleted Successfully";
            header('location:index.php'); // Changed here index to index.php
            
            
        } else {
            $_SESSION['status'] = "Data Not Deleted";
            header('location:index.php');
            
        }
    }
```

Also removed the white space from header('location: index.php'); to header('location:index.php');

Comment: Facing the same problem. Let me add a demo link

Comment: @vikashkumar No, whitespace is not significant in the syntax.

Comment: Then I think issue with unlink("uploads/" . $new_name); Please comment it and check.

Comment: @vikashkumar why not suggest to OP that they enable PHP error reporting, instead of just commenting / uncommenting lines or changing syntax at random. It's usually easier to actually get error info than to just guess. Also we don't know yet if they actually made the change from "index" to "index.php"...according to the comments in the main thread they are still waiting to report back on whether that helped.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What did you change, and why?

Comment: @NicoHaase I have changed the header('location: index'); to header('location:index.php'); and removed the white-space. Because IN Core PHP we need to add extension after page name if you are not using any htacess to hide extension. also might be white space issue in header location. But in my latest comment i suggest him to comment the unlink method and check.

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your answer** by editing it

Comment: `also might be white space issue in header location`... still not necessary or relevant, no. It would be trivial for you to test this yourself.

Comment: it's a hosting issue. I don't know how? It works perfectly on infinityfree hosting.

Comment: @ShakijMahamud  If you don't know how then do some debugging..we don't know how either, because we don't have any technical information.